# Use Regex to reposition characters after Markdown transformation

Tags: regex, markdown

This seems straightforward but I can't wrap my head around it.

In a transformation of HTML to Markdown, "bolded" text (enclosed by double asterisks and followed by a space) can output incorrectly as in the following example:

```
Avoid changing existing code to match your personal preferences (see **To 'var' or Not to 'var' **below for an example).
```

I want to run a simple Regex script to reposition the asterisks it so it reads:

```
Avoid changing existing code to match your personal preferences (see **To 'var' or Not to 'var'** below for an example).
```

There may be instances that a line has more than one bolded word/phrase, or has italicized word(s)/phrase(s) in addition (denoted in Markdown by enclosure in single asterisks). The asterisk(s) may also be appended to the previous word instead of prepended to the following word, like:

```
## ​Test Organization* (most of these points don't need to be followed for integration tests)*
```

The closest I have come is:

```
Search: (\*\*.*?)( *\*+)
Replace: $1
```

Which leaves:

```
see **To 'var' or Not to 'var' below
```

But replacing with `$1**` restores it to its original form, and I don't understand why. And I'm certain it is not taking into account the other use cases stated above.

It is not in my power to fix the Markdown transformation mechanism such that these problems are not introduced in the first place.

If anyone has thoughts I would be grateful for them. Thanks.

Comment: Try `(\*\*)\b(.*?)( +)(\*\*)` => `$1$2$4$3`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this breaks for multiple bolds `**yo** **hello  **`, outputs `**yo**** hello  **`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is what I would do](https://regex101.com/r/dfrrUE/1)

```
^((?:[^*]|\*[^*]|\*\*(?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s]\*\*)*)\*\*((?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s])(\s+)\*\*
```

And the replace string being `$1**$2**$3`, where `1` is pre-broken-bold text (including previous *working bold* text), `2` is broken-bold-text, and `3` is the text that is breaking the bold.

[image]

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/dfrrUE/2) of it correctly ignoring bold and italic in the same line.

```
**this bold is fine** and now *some italic*, but what about a lone *? **OH NO ** oh, looks like I'm fixing it
```

[image]

---

If you need an explanation on the thought process behind it, whack the regex into this site, [which will provide a visual state machine](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5E*%5D%7C%5C*%5B%5E*%5D%7C%5C*%5C*%28%3F%3A%5B%5E*%5D%7C%5C*%5B%5E*%5D%29*%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%5C*%5C*%29*%29%5C*%5C*%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5E*%5D%7C%5C*%5B%5E*%5D%29*%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%29%28%5Cs%2B%29%5C*%5C*)

[image]
It's basically saying that

1. is made up of

   - non-asterisks,
   - asterisks that dont make bold text, &/or
   - bold text that doesn't end in whitespace

     - bold text is defined as being wrapped in double asterisks,
     - containing no asterisks, and/or
     - containing asterisks that aren't followed by asterisks
2. is bold text (following double asterisks, and using the rules above)
3. is whitespace at the end of that bold text

---

Note that *most* languages don't treat the end of the last/replace match to mean `^` in subsequent matches for a global replace
E.g. in JS, see how the second OH NO doesn't get replaced?

```js
"**this bold is fine** and now *some italic*, but what about a lone *? **OH NO ** oh, looks like I'm *fixing* it **OH NO x2    **!"
    .replace(/^((?:[^*]|\*[^*]|\*\*(?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s]\*\*)*)\*\*((?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s])(\s+)\*\*/g, '$1**$2**$3')
```

`**this bold is fine** and now *some italic*, but what about a lone *? **OH NO**  oh, looks like I'm *fixing* it **OH NO x2    **!`.
So manual looping will be necessary;

```js
let output = '';
for (
    let input ="**this bold is fine** and now *some italic*, but what about a lone *? **OH NO ** oh, looks like I'm *fixing* it **OH NO x2    **!";
    output != input;
    input = input.replace(/^((?:[^*]|\*[^*]|\*\*(?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s]\*\*)*)\*\*((?:[^*]|\*[^*])*[^\s])(\s+)\*\*/, '$1**$2**$3')
) output = input;
console.log(output);
```

`**this bold is fine** and now *some italic*, but what about a lone *? **OH NO**  oh, looks like I'm *fixing* it **OH NO x2**    !`

Comment: I appreciate the explanations with the solutions - thank you @Hashbrown

Comment: @hcdocs I added a visual and verbal explanation too if you have trouble reading (understanding) the long regex itself